# 3D object detection for 2D images (logistics use case)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, 3d-object-detection

I am working on 3D object detection for parcel boxes same like amazon parcel,thinking to label with 3D cuboids but finding difficult to find a existing 3D object detection for 2D images.

As far what i have found is kitti & MMDetection only which requires point cloud data which means for those images coming from LIDAR or RADAR.

Is there any other method for object detection & do find the reference image.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: There is a CVPR paper on 3D bounding box estimation from an 2D image (3D Bounding Box Estimation Using Deep Learning and Geometry)

Comment: thanks let me have a look since 4 weeks doing research on it & this is one of the challenging problem in computer vision ,let's connect at the same time on linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/-vivek-chaudhary/

Comment: But they have used kitti dataset & this dataset has taken point cloud data from LIDAR or RADAR but images in my case will be from normal camera